# Ошибка _tkinter.TclError: bad text index "0" при вставке в Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def domeninfo():
    e3 = Entry(note2,width=25)
    e3.grid(column=0,row=0)
    textdomen = Text(note2,width=25,height=16)
    textdomen.grid(column=2,row=0)

def func():
    global tag_domen
    textdomen.delete('0.0',END)
    thetext = e3.get()
    urldomen = 'https://google.ru'+thetext # Вместо гугла там другой сайт
    reqdomen = requests.get(urldomen)
    bsdomen = BeautifulSoup(reqdomen.text,'lxml')
    tag_domen = bsdomen.find('pre').text
    textdomen.insert(0,tag_domen)
```

И самое интересное, без графического интерфейса все работает, а с ним глючит
Ошибка :

> ```
> self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
> _tkinter.TclError: bad text index "0"
> ```

Вот так работает

```
vvod = input(':')
urldomen = 'https://google.ru='+vvod
reqdomen = requests.get(urldomen)
bsdomen = BeautifulSoup(reqdomen.text,'lxml')
tag_domen = bsdomen.find('pre').text
print(tag_domen)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все, я разобрался. В индексе нужно выставить число с плавающей точкой (float), например `0.0`